# Can't send volley post request from android phone to my database

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm using volley to make my android communicate with my database by using PHP as bridge to get through database.

Below here are my Login code on **android studio** which work perfectly fine using emulator **Nexus 4 API 23**, but when i'm trying to run the App using my smartphone **Samsung A5-2017** it only works on interface but the data are not send/function as it should. Btw i'm using **SDK version 29** on this application

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText editTextNoPelajar,editTextPassword;
TextView link_register;
Button btnLogin;
private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://10.1.19.2/attendance/Login.php";
SessionManager sessionManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

    editTextNoPelajar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNoPelajar);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    link_register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRegister);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userLogin(){
   final String NoPelajar = editTextNoPelajar.getText().toString().trim();
   final String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(NoPelajar.isEmpty() || Password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill up all the requirement",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else{

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("error");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");


                            if(success.equals("0")){

                                for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String name = object.getString("Name").trim();
                                    String KodProgram = object.getString("KodProgram").trim();

                                    sessionManager.createSession(name,KodProgram);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("Name",name);
                                    intent.putExtra("KodProgram",KodProgram);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("NoPelajar",NoPelajar);
                params.put("Password",Password);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == btnLogin){
        userLogin();
    }

}

}
```

Plus i have enable all the internet permission at **Manifest** as i shown below

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Once i click button **Login** its display this

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl@8b8d06[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{9070fc7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0- 
0,0} TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@8b8d06[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@8b8d06[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[462,1596][618,1728] result=0x7 
surface={valid=true 536733736960} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@8b8d06[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(462, 1596 - 618, 1728) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 
0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@8b8d06[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputEventReceiver: channel '630e1a0 Toast (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
D/InputEventReceiver: channel '630e1a0 Toast (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=250KB, data=195KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=247KB, data=157KB
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=248KB, data=160KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=248KB, data=160KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
```

Where did i do wrong guys?.. Please help me solve this problem, its been 2 days already trying to figured out the solution. Thank you

Comment: if your concern is about request failure then can you please share the details of what you are getting inside onErrorResponse for VolleyError boject. This generally has all the details. Also the way you compare success is not the right way. Please see Volley documentation https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: Actually there is no red error that android studio highlight while i running my application on my phone. But the problem is, the data that i try to send from my phone to to the server have no respond whereas it should read and send me to home page after log in. @SusheelTickoo.

Comment: you have got to see what the php is happening

Comment: My PHP work perfectly fine because i has test it with **Postman**.  Is there any possibilities of what happened  is because my server XAMPP is in localhost mode and didn't online?  @RajuyourPepe

Comment: Android studio will not highlight any run time or logical errors. If your request is getting properly queued by the statement  requestQueue.add(stringRequest); then it will definitely  land inside onResponse or onErrorResponse . What you have to do is , Debug your code (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) and check where the control is landing. If none of the methods is getting called then you have not setup your Volley library properly and your request is not getting queued up.

Comment: i think you should use JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest with JSONObject containing your user and password